# Disable Key Back event when entry a page - Windows 10 Mobile c#

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-10, back, windows-10-mobile

I have a function to return to the previous page when I click the back button hardware, but I want this event to be disabled on a given page (is a popup that has a page in).

I want to turn off because when I want to return to the previous page, the popup remains visible and only navigates backward on the page which is under the popup, this is when I open the popup it shall not enter into the stack of visited pages that the system can return back down.

the code that I have to get back is:

```
public NavigationService(Frame frame)
{
    bool BackHardwareButtonisPresent = true;
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s, a) =>
            {
                if (BackHardwareButtonisPresent)
                {
                    if (this.CanGoBack)
                    {
                        this.GoBack();
                        a.Handled = true;
                    }
                }
            };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the property which is bound to the popup `IsOpen` property to check before navigating back.

```
 if (this.CanGoBack && !IsPopupOpen)
    {
       this.GoBack();
       a.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Great @Bells. Thanks very much. :)